# fetch request failed on react-native

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am currently learning react-native and I am having an issue with fetch request. 
It's giving me an error in the image shown below.

**Note: I test the url with react, and it works there. But for some reason it does not work on react-native.

The code:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      data: null,
      error: null
   }
}
componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('https://ptx.transportdata.tw/MOTC/v2/Bike/Availability/Taipei?$format=JSON')
       .then((res) => res.json())
       .then((resJson) => {
          this.setState( {
             isLoading: false,
             data: resJson,
          })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
           console.log(error);
           this.setState({
               error: error
           })
         })
 }
```

The error is the following:
[error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H70hD.png)

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. You don't need a return statement in componentDidMount.
2. When I try to fetch the URL, I got a 401 unauthorized. According to their API docs you need an app id and api key. Are you setting those when making the request?

Comment: 1. Noted
2. where in the api doc did it say that I need the app id and api key? because when I used it on regular react app, I got it to work
Also --> here's where I originally got the api: 
https://ptx.transportdata.tw/MOTC/Swagger/ (the explanations are all in chinese)